# Dynamically change embeded abc notaion using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, notation

Given is a web page using abc notation scripts:

```
<script src="js/abc2svg-1.js"></script>
<script src="js/xmlplay_emb.js"></script>
```

and with this embeded score (example):

```
<div class="abc">
X:1
T:
M:
L:1/4
K:C
V:1 clef=treble
CD_EFG_A_B
</div>
```

Is it possible to exchange notes by using JavaScript?
How can i rerender dom manipulated data?

Comment: You want to change the input of your html or share with others?

Comment: Let's say i have the notes "CEG" hard coded in html. By clickling a button the notes (and the rendered svg representation) shall change into "GBD" for example.